# Renaming filenames in two directories IF certain characters between them match - vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector, range, renaming

My first job as an intern was to write a program to compare certain characters in the filenames of two different directories, and if they match, rename them. I wrote a custom code to match the characters. The initial few files get renamed in both directories, but it breaks after a point, giving a vector subscript out of range error.

I have an idea of how to fix such a vector range error from all the other posts, but nothing seemed to work. Any input would be appreciated!

PS: I am not a coder and this is my third official program. I understand the code is a bit messy.

Here is the code:

```
#include<dirent.h>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>

int main()
{
    cout << "Comparer - Renamer v.0.1.beta\n\n";
    string dr1, dr2;
    int x, y;

    DIR           *d1;
    struct dirent *dir1;
    vector<string> a;
    a.reserve(25000);
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Enter the first directory (format : log_2017...) : ";
    cin >> dr1;
    d1 = opendir(dr1.c_str());
    if (d1){
        while ((dir1 = readdir(d1)) != NULL){
            i++;
            a.push_back(dir1->d_name);
        }
        closedir(d1);
    }
    x = a.size();


    cout << "\nEnter the second directory (format : 2017.12...) : ";
    cin >> dr2;
    DIR           *d2;
    struct dirent *dir2;
    vector<string> b;
    b.reserve(25000);
    int j = 0;
    d2 = opendir(dr2.c_str());
    if (d2){
        while ((dir2 = readdir(d2)) != NULL){
            j++;
            b.push_back(dir2->d_name);
        }
        closedir(d2);
    }
    y = b.size();

    ostringstream osa, nsa, osb, nsb;
    string oldname_a, newname_a, oldname_b, newname_b;
    int u, v, w;

    for (int l = 2; l < x; l++){
        for (int k = l; k < y; k++){
            int c = a[l][20] * 10 + a[l][21];
            int d = b[k][14] * 10 + b[k][15];
            int e = a[l][17] * 10 + a[l][18];
            int f = b[k][11] * 10 + b[k][12];

            if (a[l][4] == b[k][0] && a[l][5] == b[k][1] && a[l][6] == b[k][2] && a[l][7] == b[k][3] && a[l][9] == b[k][5] && a[l][10] == b[k][6] && a[l][12] == b[k][8] && a[l][13] == b[k][9]){
                u = 0;
            }
            else{
                u = 1;
            }
            if ((e - f) == 0 && abs(c - d) < 12){
                v = 0;
            }
            else{
                v = 1;
            }
            if ((e - f) == 1 && ((c == 58) || (c == 59) || (c == 0) || (c == 1) || (c == 2))){
                w = 0;
            }
            else{
                w = 1;
            }

            if (u == 0 && (v == 0 || w == 0)){
                osa.str(string());
                osa << dr1 << "\\" << a[l];
                nsa.str(string());
                nsa << dr1 << "\\" << l - 1 << ". " << a[l];
                oldname_a = osa.str();
                newname_a = nsa.str();

                osb.str(string());
                osb << dr2 << "\\" << b[k];
                nsb.str(string());
                nsb << dr2 << "\\" << l - 1 << ". " << b[k];
                oldname_b = osb.str();
                newname_b = nsb.str();

                rename(oldname_a.c_str(), newname_a.c_str())
                rename(oldname_b.c_str(), newname_b.c_str())
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Presently the code is set such that it shows me how the comparison between the filenames is made.

Comment: `a.reserve(25000);` This doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger? What line is causing the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: You should have one of the software mentors at your company show you how to use a debugger.

Comment: Your code would be more readable if you used character literals instead of their decimal ASCII value.

Comment: [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know if all directory entry names guaranteed to be at least 21 characters long. It wants to remind you of the two metafolders: . and .. .

Comment: I strongly recommend giving variables meaningful names. Right now your code reads like a bowl of alphabet soup and would probably fail a code review.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs! I will get to work on them asap!

Comment: I believe the problem lies within the nested for loop. After debugging, everything before the for loop and the statements within the loop check out. The basic logic I want it to do is -> if a[0] = b[0] replace a[0] and b[0] (which is effectively oldname_a(or b) with newname_a(or b). Otherwise, check for a[0] = b[1] and so on. 

But once a[0] = b[0] and the renaming is done, the next check would be for is a[1] = b[1] (and not b[0]) hence the k = l initialization in the second loop.

Comment: And yes, the directory entry names are over 30 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was not debugging properly, and the problem was in this part of the code:

```
int c = a[l][20] * 10 + a[l][21];
int d = b[k][14] * 10 + b[k][15];
int e = a[l][17] * 10 + a[l][18];
int f = b[k][11] * 10 + b[k][12];
```

I did not know that I couldn't assign an integer from a string/char directly to an int. I converted the char to int (which would give me the ASCII value of the char) and then subtracted it by 48 to convert it to decimal (I do not know if there is an easier way to do this, but this seemed to have worked for me!) The modified part looks like this:

```
c = ((int)a[l][20] - 48) * 10 + ((int)a[l][21] - 48);
d = ((int)b[k][14] - 48) * 10 + ((int)b[k][15] - 48);
e = ((int)a[l][17] - 48) * 10 + ((int)a[l][18] - 48):
f = ((int)b[k][11] - 48) * 10 + ((int)b[k][12] - 48);
```

There was also a small manual error in the conditions, which I also rectified.